# Error while installing skype in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: skype

I am new to Linux and installed Linux 16.04 LTS. While i tried to install skype i did some mistake and now on the top write corner it is showing an error. "E: The package skypeforlinux needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it"

I tried to use canonical partners package update, but it shows failed to load package list.

Can you please tell me how to get skype installed.
Thanks
tapas

Comment: You probably deleted some files manually, that was wrong. `skypeforlinux` is the 5.0 beta. Install it again from a deb file.

Comment: Since you mentioned Canonical Partner I want to chime in that while the old Skype client (version 4.3.0.37) is available in Canonical Partner, the new client (`skypeforlinux`) is not (at least not yet). So once installed correctly, updates are achieved from Skype's repository, not Canonical Partner.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Skype .deb file at https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ and just reinstall it.

Be forewarned that you **may** end up with duplicate repository files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` named:

- skype-stable.list
- skypeforlinux.list

and you'll probably need to delete the second one, or future software updates may error out...

In `terminal`...

Confirm that the first file exists...

```
ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

if the first file exists, then delete the second file...

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skypeforlinux.list
```

Comment: You mix up Skype 4.3 and Skype 5.0 beta.

Comment: @Pilot6 no, I just went through this with another user. You'd think that the skypeforlinux-64.deb file (which is actually the beta) would install the skypeforlinux.list file, but it doesn't, it installs skype-stable.list, and if the user has previously installed Skype beta, they'll end up with two .list files, and software update will complain. It looks like Microsoft changed the names of the .list files when they decided that the beta was now stable (and they forgot to delete the original beta .list file themselves).